# Can't Connect to External MYSQL database from Heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

My Ruby app connects to 2 databases in production: a PG database on the heroku server(successful) and a remote mysql database (unsuccessful).

The database URLs are stored in environment variables (in application.yml locally, and in config vars on Heroku).

The app is successfully retrieving data from both of these databases in development mode, so I know the URLs and credentials are valid.

On Heroku, only the pg connection is successful; 
the MySQL connection throws a generic error: `Mysql2::Error (Can't connect to MySQL server on 'villageprint.mypresswise.com' (110)):`.
So both URLs are definitely being read from the config vars but the MYSQL connection is still unsuccessful.

Is there any reason the MySQL database might not accept the connection from Heroku?  Or is it more likely that the connection is failing due to some application error? How can I debug this?

Comment: It's just Ruby. No need to YELL. This is not a COMIC BOOK.

Comment: It's highly probable that your MySQL doesn't allow remote connections because having port 3306 open to the general public is a super bad plan. If you need to connect remotely to it consider using an SSH tunnel or VPN-type connection.

Comment: @tadman I think you're right - I just tested by trying to connect via command line while using my iPhone hotspot for wifi - I received a warning about security and was unable to proceed...

Comment: Connecting to external databases is always a risky proposition. On occasions when I've had to do it SSH is the most convenient, you can use that to forward ports, and because it can be secured with a key it's not something people can just stumble upon and access. If you don't need a real-time connection consider dumping the MySQL data and importing it on your Heroku side on a regular basis, like a batch job, perhaps even over a simple API you can lock down properly.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it's for real time data - will look into ssh.